# Bean mapper with @SqlQuery and @RegisterBeanMapper cant instantiate JDBI V3

Tags: java, jdbi

I cant not use Jdbi with a Dao Interface as the documentation shows, see http://jdbi.org/#_reflection_mappers
it throws next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A bean, model.tipolog.TipoLog, was mapped which was not instantiable
```

```java
List<TipoLog> tipoLogs1=jdbi.withExtension(TipoLogDao.class,dao->{
        return dao.listAllLogs();
});

public interface TipoLogDao {
    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM tamble")
    @RegisterBeanMapper(TipoLog.class)
    List<TipoLog> listAllLogs();
}

public class TipoLog {

    private String IdTipoLog;
    private String Nombre;
    private String Descripcion;
    private String Activo;

    @ConstructorProperties({"IdTipoLog", "Nombre", "Descripcion", "Activo"})
    public TipoLog(String IdTipoLog, String Nombre, String Descripcion, String Activo) {
        this.IdTipoLog = IdTipoLog;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Descripcion = Descripcion;
        this.Activo = Activo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This solution works, but if you want to use a specific constructor (not the default one), then this answer is not the one you are looking for. As said by [Jigar Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60940986/116327), Use `@RegisterConstructorMapper` instead of `@RegisterBeanMapper`. A `BeanMapper` uses only the default constructor and set properties values. To use a specific constructor, the solution is to use a `ConstructorMapper`.

Your `TipoLog` class needs a **default constructor**. This works:

`User.java`

```java
import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;

public class User {
    int id;
    String name;

    // required default constructor
    public User() {
        super();
    }

    @ConstructorProperties({ "id", "name" })
    public User(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getter, setter, hashCode, equals, toString
}
```

`UserDao.java`

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.config.RegisterBeanMapper;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.SqlQuery;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.SqlUpdate;

public interface UserDao {
    @SqlUpdate("CREATE TABLE user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR)")
    void createTable();

    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO user(id, name) VALUES (?, ?)")
    void insertPositional(int id, String name);

    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name")
    @RegisterBeanMapper(User.class)
    List<User> listUsers();
}
```

`ConstructorPropertiesExplore.java`

```java
import java.util.List;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectPlugin;

public class ConstructorPropertiesExplore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        jdbi.installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());

        List<User> users = jdbi.withExtension(UserDao.class, dao -> {
            dao.createTable();
            dao.insertPositional(0, "Alice");
            dao.insertPositional(1, "Bob");
            dao.insertPositional(2, "Clarice");
            dao.insertPositional(3, "David");

            return dao.listUsers();
        });

        assertThat(users).containsExactly(new User(0, "Alice"), new User(1, "Bob"), new User(2, "Clarice"),
                new User(3, "David"));
    }

}
```

Comment: it works perfect, but how could i improve this? because it has a default constructor

Comment: What do you want to improve? I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a default constructor. 
Use @RegisterConstructorMapper instead of @RegisterBeanMapper.